# instanceof with shared prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype, instanceof

The following code logs 'true' 4 times:

```
var menuItem = {
    name: "New menuItem",
};

function food(name) {
    if(name) this.name = name;
    //this.resourceType = "food";
}
food.prototype = menuItem;

function drink(name) {
    if(name) this.name = name;
    //this.resourceType = "drink";
}
drink.prototype = menuItem;

var burger = new food();
var coke = new drink();

console.log(buger instanceof food);
console.log(burger instanceof drink);
console.log(coke instanceof food);
console.log(coke instanceof drink);
```

However if I comment out the following two lines:

```
//food.prototype = menuItem;
//drink.prototype = menuItem;
```

Then the code does what I want and logs true for "buger instanceof food" and "coke instanceof drink".

Is there a way of checking if the menuItem is an instance of either food or drink correctly while they both share the same prototype (menuItem)?

I'd prefer not to have to store the type like so:

```
this.resourceType = "food";
```

If there is a better way of doing it.

Comment: You have some typos related to *burger/buger*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each constructor, create a new object to use as the `prototype` of that constructor, and have each new prototype object use `menuItem` as *its* prototype:

```
food.prototype = Object.create(menuItem);
```

So the prototype chain for a `food` instance and `drink` instance now looks like:

```
[food instance] > [food prototype] > [menuItem]
[drink instance] > [drink prototype] > [menuItem]
```

The old chain looked like:

```
[food instance] > [menuItem]
[drink instance] > [menuItem]
```

As you can see, in the old chain, a `food` instance and `drink` instance really had the same prototype parent, so a `food`-constructed object and `drink`-constructed object has the same prototype parent. Under the new system, `food` and `drink` have separate prototype parents.

MDN has a good description of `instanceof`:

> The `instanceof` operator tests whether an object has in its prototype chain the `prototype` property of a constructor.

So, when you test `burger instanceof drink` you're testing "*is `drink.prototype` in the prototype chain of `burger`?*". Previously, `drink.prototype` was equal to `menuItem`, so you were really testing "*is `menuItem` in the prototype chain of `burger`?*". Now, `drink.prototype` is its own unique value, separate from `food.prototype`, so the result is `false`.

Comment: Could you show me how the old prototype chain looked, please?

Comment: @Jimmay Added more explanation.